# sample data for training neural networks for self-driving cars

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

If I ask the question in the wrong forum, let me know, I will delete it. 
I want see sample data for training neural networks for self-driving cars. I understand that there will be geodata and image recognition.I can’t find on the Internet a real example of how neural networks are trained for unmanned vehicles.I'm still new, but this topic is interesting to me. Can anybody prompt resources where i can look at the data for learning this type of neural networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for datasets for training autonomous driving cars? or are you looking for a tutorial/source of knowledge to learn how to train autonomous driving cars?

**For datasets**, the following 2 are free to download:

[Berkeley dataset](http://bdd-data.berkeley.edu/) - 100,000 HD video sequences of over 1,100-hour driving experience across many different times in the day, weather conditions, and driving scenarios

[BDD100K](https://bair.berkeley.edu/blog/2018/05/30/bdd/) - I'm not sure if it isn't the same as the first one (no personal experience).

[Nuscenes dataset](https://www.nuscenes.org/) - Full sensor data (multiple sensor types and positions). Their site also include a tutorial of how to use their dataset.

I'm sure you can find more in the following link:
[50 Free Machine Learning Datasets: Self-Driving Cars](https://blog.cambridgespark.com/50-free-machine-learning-datasets-self-driving-cars-d37be5a96b28)

**For knowledge/tutorial**:

As I mentioned before, the last dataset contains a tutorial.
There is also the [MIT tutorial](https://selfdrivingcars.mit.edu/tutorials/).
You can also read [DeepDriving: Learning Affordance for Direct Perception in Autonomous Driving](http://deepdriving.cs.princeton.edu/), it is a paper from ICCV2015 and they include their source code.

I'm sure there are many more sources.